# Output size issue using mapply

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, mapply

I want to add another column to `df = data.frame(Start = c(0, 8, 0, 8), Length = c(8, 8, 8, 8))` called Hour, which will be a nested column, each row containing Start[i]:(Start[i] + Length[i] - 1).

In the past I have used something similar to this:  `df %>% mutate(Hour = mapply(function(x, y) x:(x + y - 1), Start, Length))` but this doesn't seem to work, giving the error

`` Error in `mutate()`: ! Problem while computing `Hour = mapply(function(x, y) x:(x + y - 1), Start, Length)`. ✖ `Hour` must be size 4 or 1, not 8. ``

I have no idea why this is happening as I thought mapply is the appropriate thing to do here. I also have a similar (bigger) data frame to `df` where this line of code (which leads to the error in `df`) actually works? Anyone know what is going on here? As well as what the fix is? Thanks

Comment: Can you write your expected output for 'Hour'?

Comment: add `SIMPLIFY = FALSE` to `mapply`. It worked before because you probably had different length vectors. Here all lengths are 8 so `mapply` returns simplified output (matrix).